# How to check a column contains null value using SQL's in Spanner Database

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

How to check a column containing null value using SQL's in Spanner Database. I have both String and Timestamp columns types. When I try to write the below query I am always getting value in the column as result .If the column is null its prints like null;

```
        select 
         case when t.locked_by IS  null   then 'A'
            else t.locked_by
          end
    from Temp1 t where name='test2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really see anything wrong with the query, and I cannot reproduce the issue myself. But you could try to use [`COALESCE`](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#coalesce) instead of the `CASE WHEN` operator:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t.locked_by, 'A')
FROM Temp1 t
WHERE name='test2'
```

Comment: Yes you are right,its working (both coalesec and case).I have made one mistake by typing null manually in Editor instead of setting null vai update statement .